# How can I get smaller CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, settings

Is it possible to get a smaller CheckBox, like the one used in Settings application? I'd like to use it in my own custom Preference class, to mimic Android UI more closely...

Thank you for your time,
Kipple

Comment: AFAIK, they are all the same size. You may wish to consider adding screenshots that demonstrate what you consider the different sizes to be.

Comment: True... I was comparing emulator ones to my HTC phone one... HTC seems to have tweaked a little CheckBox buttons.

http://i50.tinypic.com/bjfn2s.jpg <- HTC version is show first

Thanks CommonsWare

Comment: maybe it would helpful to create your own component and get selector and drawable files from android.jar?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference between HTC and vanilla Google Android drawables for CheckBox...